# Disable filtering option on the list after the webpart page has loaded loaded completly

Tags: list, sharepoint-enterprise, filter

I am filtering a list by passing query string to a custom list

```
http://TestSite/TestSubsite/Lists/TestList/allitems.aspx?FilterField1=FirstName &FilterValue1=Apelles
```

This does the job of filtering the list, but once its done i want the filtering options on the column header either to be locked or unclickable so that nobody filter it further 
below is the screen shot of one column
[image]

Comment: Since the filter parameters will be on the URL, they can change them anyway. Does disabling the filtering options on the columns make sense? If so, do you want to disable all columns or just the one you are filtering on currently?

Comment: Hi Marc, i want to disable only the column that i am currenlty filtering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add some script to the page to alter or disable the behavior on the Contact Name column header. If you write the function generically, you could apply it to multiple columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using SharePoint designer. Open the page where u have added the list view web part. Then find the column for which you want to disable the filter inside XSLT WP. Add a "filterable" attribute.

`<FieldRef Name="Contact Name" Filterable="False" />`